# Adding layout constraint for a programatically created UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I created a UIButton programatically and I want to add constraint 
so that it will stay at the same length from the bottom so it 
will look right on both the iPhone 4 and 5.

I know how to do it in Interface Builder but don't know how to do it programatically.

Comment: i dont understand what u want ?? u want to check it is iphone 4 or iphone 5 ??

Comment: No, I want the button to stay in the same length from the bottom when it is an iphone 4 or 5 because of the different screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put Following line in **.pch** file

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

and write code for `iPhone 5` as Below

```
if( IS_IPHONE_5 )
      // Set Fram/ code for iPhone 5
else
     // Set Fram/ code for iPhone 4
```